# How to deploy App to Apple Store with repopulated database(SQLite)?

Tags: ios, react-native, sqlite

I am developing my mobile app using react-native, and database goes with it, I am using `SQLite storage`.

**The way I work with it:**
create it using python script and copy it to path where virtual device takes.
Obviously I need somehow to bundle it within my app in order to run on real device?

**I have 2 options in mind:**
 1. Keep state of app using AsyncStorage, where to store isDBCreated
    variable, so we creat DB from json file that is shipped with the app
    only once and then use it on consequent runs
 2. Somehow bundle created DB

With 1 - I am confident and know how to do it
With 2 - don't know ( I have followed [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage) in order to bundle it on IOS, but without luck)

From your experience, what is the best way to bundle database?